# iwlist scanning without root privileges

Tags: linux, wifi, network-interface

I'm writing application where I need to scan one of wireless interfaces. In the past, my program was run with `sudo` and I used (in code):

```
iwlist wlanX scan
```

But now I want to allow to run program without root privileges. Will it be relatively safe if I change capabilities of `/sbin/iwlist` to `cap_net_admin+eip`? `Iwlist` is only for showing detailed wireless informations so broader access to this command probably is not very dangereous, right?

Comment: Why not simply modify your script to run `sudo iwlist wlanX scan` and configure `sudo` to run the command without asking for a password?

Comment: Is this better solution? Why? Do you mean modify `sudoers` file, right? If my application will be installed from deb on  other computer how should I do this change (I don't know the name of user)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure `sudo` so that members of a group can run a command without a password. Use `visudo` to edit the `sudoers` file:

```
# visudo
```

Add something similar to:

```
%mygroup ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: iwlist wlanX scan
```

to the bottom of the file (where `mygroup` is the name of your group preceded with a percent symbol).

You could also allow a single user to run this by changing `%mygroup` to `myuser`, where `myuser` is the username (note the lack of a percent symbol).

Or, you could allow everyone to scan by replacing `%mygroup` with `ALL`.

Using `capabilities` allows `cap_net_admin` for all `iwlist` commands wheras using `sudo` configured as above limits it to just one command with specific options.  That has to be more secure.

Another (general) reason is that configuring `sudo` would be more portable than using `capabilites`, although that isn't relevant in this instance if you're just using to Linux.

Comment: `>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 32 <<<`

Line 32 is `mat ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: iwlist wlan0 scan`

Comment: Check lines before 32? It does say **near** :-)

Comment: The error is on line 32 - if I remove that line then it works. All of the rest of my sudoers file is the default.

Comment: I got rid of that error by using this `mat ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iw` but now I just get `command failed: Operation not permitted (-1)` when I run `/sbin/iw wlan0 scan`

Comment: I've tried again. Used `mat ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iw wlan0 scan` this time and it worked. One thing I didn't realise before is that you still have to specify `sudo` it just doesn't ask for a password anymore.

Answer (score 2):

if not obsessed with `iwlist scan` and [wpa_supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_cli) is installed, you may try:

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 scan > /dev/null; sleep 5; wpa_cli -i wlan0 scan_results
```

It does not require root privilege to run. And its output is similar to csv format which makes it easy to be parsed.

```
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:aa   5220    -26 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   AP-5G
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:bb   5745    -62 [WPA-PSK-CCMP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]  AP2
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:cc   2412    -50 [WPA-PSK-CCMP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]  AP3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure `sudo` to not ask for a password.

Type in `visudo` and add lines such as this:

```
myuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iw wlan0 scan
myuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan
```

or

```
%mygroup ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iw wlan0 scan
%mygroup ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Note that you need to specify the full path to `iw` and that you still need to run using `sudo` but now you won't be prompted for your password.

```
sudo iw wlan0 scan
```

Thanks [@garethTheRed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29406/gareththered) for part of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for this, a one-liner, was to set the `setuid` bit on the binary I wanted to execute (in my case, `iwconfig`):

```
sudo chmod u+s /sbin/iwconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

If Network Manager is used on the system, then sudo privilege is not needed. Simply run:

```
nmcli dev wifi rescan
```

Immediately following this command (for maybe 30 seconds), the full list of available WiFi networks is visible, even to other tools.

For example, in my test:

```
iwlist scan             # lists 1 AP
nmcli dev wifi rescan
iwlist scan             # lists 8 APs
```